# Why does this code execute printf 8 times from forking?

Tags: c, printf, fork

Studying for finals, I got stuck on this problem. They ask how many times the following code executes printf:

```
#include    "csapp.h"
void    doit()  {   
Fork();
Fork();
printf("hello\n");
return; 
}
int main()
{
doit();
printf("hello\n");
exit(0);
}
```

The solutions say that it printf executes 8 times, but I cannot figure out why. I've been trying to draw the picture of what's going on in the code, but my pictures make it seem like it only execute 4 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 forks - Four processes. Each process has two `printfs` with `hello` (one in `main` and one in `doit` - hence 8.